Updating two different nodes using XSLT
Updating two different nodes using XSLT
Input -
<root>
    <Bank>
        <BankDetail>
            <Name1>
            </Name1>
            <Name2>TestBank</Name2>
        </BankDetail>
    </Bank>
    <Item>
        <Item1>1235</Item1>
    </Item>
</root>

Existing XSLT
The XSLT is doing one task of copying the value from Name2 Tag to Name1.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="varName">
        <xsl:if test="/root/Bank/BankDetail/Name1 = ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="/root/Bank/BankDetail/Name2"/2
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/root/Bank/BankDetail/Name1">
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$varName"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Now, another update needs to be made using the same XSLT. Replacing the <Item1> value 1235 with "Item No 1" string.
Need this in XSLT 1.0
Desired Output -
<root>
    <Bank>
        <BankDetail>
            <Name1>TestBank</Name1>
            <Name2>TestBank</Name2>
        </BankDetail>
    </Bank>
    <Item>
        <Item1>Item No 1</Item1>
    </Item>
</root>

I am new to the XSLT. Please let me know if we have any way to do the updates in same XSLT.
This is my best attempt
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" version="1.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:variable name="varName">
    <xsl:if test="xml/Bank/BankDetail/Name1 = ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="xml/Bank/BankDetail/Name2"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="varItem" select="'Item No 1'"/>

<xsl:template match="xml/Bank/BankDetail/Name1">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$varName"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xml/Item/Item1">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$varItem"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>

The Output its giving as
<xml>
<Bank>
    <BankDetail>
        <Name1>TestBank</Name1>
        <Name2>TestBank</Name2>
    </BankDetail>
</Bank>
<Item>
    <Item1>Item No 11235</Item1>
</Item>

Not sure why this is appending with existing value rather overriding.

Please ask a specific question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

I had tried to use the Template match and Apply template twice for both the updates but looks like its copying all the nodes twice with out updating the 2nd node. Please help me with some suggestion to d this.

Post your best attempt.

Please refer above.

If the input is e.g.
<root>
    <Bank>
        <BankDetail>
            <Name1>
            </Name1>
            <Name2>TestBank</Name2>
        </BankDetail>
    </Bank>
    <Item>
        <Item1>1235</Item1>
    </Item>
</root>

then I think
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:variable name="varItem" select="'Item No 1'"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="root/Bank/BankDetail/Name1[not(normalize-space())]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="/root/Bank/BankDetail/Name2"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="root/Item/Item1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$varItem"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

to conditionally (if Name1 doesn't have anything more but whitespace) fill Name1 with the Name2 value and to unconditionally fill Item1 with that constant value from the variable.
I am not sure that captures your intent as you haven't really spelled out any possible variations of input and output but I hope it gets you an idea on how to start with the identity transformation template and add further one for the node or element wise transformations/changes you want to perform.

Than you so much. I understand now.
